# Taxes on stocks in the US

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, switzerland

Currently, I'm a resident in the US. I plan to move to Switzerland in sometime in the next 3 years.

I have currently bought some stocks, whose value I expect to appreciate over time. I might decide to hold these shares, and eventually sell them while in Switzerland.

If I receive a net-gain upon selling these stocks, I believe I would most definitely be taxed in Switzerland. Would I however, have to pay taxes in the US as well, given that I bought the shares while I was in the US?

[EDIT]

I am not a citizen of the US.

Comment: Are you a US Citizen?

Comment: @Joe No I am not. I should have mentioned this in the question, I'll make an edit, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to USA tax law, America is a country that vigorously pursues taxes worldwide. So don’t expect to avoid a U.S. tax debt by moving overseas if you are a citizen of the United States. You are still obliged to file your tax return every year and if you had paid less taxes in Switzerland than you would in the USA then you will be required to pay the difference.

Comment: Thanks. Does this answer hold if I am not a citizen of the US?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_Switzerland), Switzerland does not impose an income tax on the sale of shares. They do impose a property tax of 0.3-0.5% annually on your net worth. As the other answers say, if you are a US citizen, you will have to pay tax on the sale in the US.

Answer (score 1):

It's not relevant where you were when you bought the stocks. Where you are a resident when you're either selling the shares or have realized gains MTM wise (depending on jurisdiction, cannot comment in Switzerland).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you owe taxes in both countries. But.
Depending on the country where you pay taxes, they will be considered against your US taxes - or not. You need to check in the Internet for a tax agreement between Switzerland and the USA.

Probably they *do* I have a tax agreement and then you would only pay in the US potential higher taxes. As Switzerland has probably the higher taxes (my guess), you would have to pay nothing in the US (you would still have to *file* though)